# What are Statement Open Time, Statement Fetch Time, and Statement Close Time in DB2 for i?

Tags: sql, db2

I can't find this in the documentation, and while I can somewhat guess based on observed behavior, I'd prefer to get a more official answer.

Open and Close times: Time required to set up and close/commit large transactions or cursors?
Fetch time: Time required to load data from the disk and return the results to the caller? (This seems to be large when one of the intermediate steps is huge but the output is relatively tiny)

Optimization time is reported separately, so is *probably* not included in any of the above.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking back at some materials from the IBM SQL Performance Workshop (***Highly recomended***)   My Understanding is

Open

- Authentication
- Open Data Path  (ODP) creation

Fetch

- CPU/Disk Ops

Run (Open + Fetch + the below if INSERT/UPDATE)

- Trigger Processing
- Locking
- Constraint Enforcement
- Index Maint
- Journaling

I don't see anything spelled out for `Close`.  But I'd guess `Close` is ODP deletion and other cleanup.